# QPainter set QBrush to drawText in QT/C++

Tags: c++, qt

I posted before about text not displaying - I got that working but by a slightly different method - setting a stylesheet(around the constructor).  The thing is - I am trying to set up a fadeout by setting the brush color to a calculated and decreasing fraction of the total color at initial display(#bbbbbb).  What I see though because I use the stylesheet is the text appearing for 10 seconds (as that's the planned fadeout cycle) and then it disappears without fading out.  But without the stylesheet setting color: #bbbbbb;, the text will not show.  Here is my code for that text:

```
if((getFrame() >= 0) && (getFrame() < 10))
    {
    int iColorComponent = ((10 - getFrame()) / 10) * 0xbb;

    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(iColorComponent, iColorComponent, iColorComponent), Qt::SolidPattern));
    painter.drawText(245, 330, 125, 15, Qt::AlignCenter, tr("Ready"));
    }
```

getFrame() returns a qint64 so it initializes as -1 and when things start then, it is set to 0.  There's a QTimer firing off every 250 ms and in that method it increments the frame field and calls update().  This is inside my paintEvent() protected method where this drawText is.  I'm using QT 5.15 and C++ 11 if any of that makes a difference.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qt use QPen for drawing text. Set a pen instead of brush for QPainter:

```
painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(iColorComponent, iColorComponent, iColorComponent), Qt::SolidPattern));
painter.drawText(245, 330, 125, 15, Qt::AlignCenter, tr("Ready"));
```

Comment: Thank you SOOOO MUCH!  I wish people had told me that in the last question I posted - I was told the code looked fine.  I had seen on the documentation about setting the brush so I did that and couldn't figure out why it wasn't displaying the text.  Now it's displaying - Not fading out but I think it's a problem with the math of calculating the color for the pen when fading lol :)  Thank you again!  I one-upped and accepted the answer for you so your reputation can improve :-D